# This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I searched on google but it is giving the answers on PHP. This error occurred in servlet. I checked the code, it's correct. To confirm the code is correct I debug the code and there is nothing wrong.

Still Getting This error.

Comment: You'll need to provide more info. What server are you using to run your servlet code? 500 indicates often a runtime exception in the java code. When you debug, do you debug "inside the server"? You should see a stack trace of the error in the server log or output console.

Comment: I am using  Glassfish server. And i will check in log. Thank you.